# Kubelet SyncLoop stops (v1.1.1)

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to resize a replication controller from 2 to 0, the two pods that are to be deleted are scheduled on node1 and node2 respectively. The pod on node2 gets deleted without a problem, but the one on node1 stays active and running according to both `kubectl get pods` and `docker ps`

### symptoms:

```
kubectl scale rc my-app-v1 --replicas=0
kubectl get rc my-app-v1
# waited several minutes
kubectl get pods -l app=my-app
```

### output:

```
CONTROLLER   CONTAINER(S)   IMAGE(S)           SELECTOR     REPLICAS
my-app-v1    my-app         <docker image>     <selector>   0

NAME                 READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE  NODE
my-app-v1-a12da      1/1       Running   0          5d   node1
```

One of the two pods got deleted properly, while the other remains running. I have tried this several times and have consistently had problems with only node1.

### What I have tried to fix it:

I ssh'ed into node1 and restarted kubelet. This deleted the pod that was lingering around, but When I try to delete another pod on that node I still have to restart kubelet to get it to work.

I think the kubelet loop is stuck somewhere and only makes it through a few iterations before getting stuck.

I just turned on verbose logging, but I'm not sure what I should look for.

### Update

This also applies to containers scheduled to node1. Their images are never pulled, nor are they started.

node1 has worked in the past and I just started running into this problem last night

#### Kubelet Version

```
admin@node1 ~ $ /opt/bin/kubelet --version=true
Kubernetes v1.1.1
```

#### Kubectl version

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"0", GitVersion:"v1.0.6", GitCommit:"388061f00f0d9e4d641f9ed4971c775e1654579d", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1", GitVersion:"v1.1.1", GitCommit:"92635e23dfafb2ddc828c8ac6c03c7a7205a84d8", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

### Log Excerpts: where is SyncLoop?

```
8154 config.go:382] Receiving a new pod "my-app-v1-a12da_default"
...
8154 server.go:944] GET /stats/default/my-app-v1-a12da/<some uuid>/app-container: (75.513µs) 404 [[Go 1.1 package http]
```

Normally the SyncLoop would pick this up and do the necessary docker operations to get the container started. But there is no sync loop activity after "Receiving new pod" and there hasn't been for the past 50 minutes since I restarted kubelet.

Comment: Would you post the log of the kubelet on the affected node during the time when you deleted the pod?  That will make this easier to diagnose.

Comment: @PaulMorie sure, I have verbosity cranked to 10 on both a healthy node and the problem node, Is there anything in particular I could grep for to find the spot where the delete request should be happening?

Comment: Could you check the version of your master by running `kubectl version`? For v1.0.+ versions, kubelet is *not* responsible for deleting the pod objects from the apisever. Since you still see the pods in `kubectl get pods`, it's likely that there are other issues in your cluster.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated with the kubectl version, what service is responsible for deleting and creating pods in v1.0+?

Comment: Your server version is v1.1, which assumes that kubelet would delete the pods. To handle the version skew, the [fix] (https://github.com/mikedanese/kubernetes/commit/a072d847476b3d146aea86c7c975743ad123cf8e) was merged to instruct the node controller to delete the pods for the node if the node reports that the kubelet version is < 1.1.0

Comment: If this is the case then how come all my other nodes are fine even though they run the same kubelet version?

Comment: Now that I have established that I am using v1.1.1 (see main post) what is responsible for creating/deleting pods on the node?

Comment: From the [github issue] (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/18523#issuecomment-164286278) , you said "You are correct. I accidentally had 1.0.7 installed first before upgrading to 1.1.1 how would I detect and correct for version skew?" Can you make sure that you upgrade all the nodes to v1.1.1 to match your master components and see if the problem remains?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @yu-ju-hong, this was due to a bug in Kubernetes 1.1.1 in handling version-skewed clusters. Please upgrade the master to a newer version, such as Kubernetes 1.1.7, and, ideally, upgrade the nodes to the same version as soon as possible.